# Getting wrong signature while using etherjs in react native

Tags: solidity, react, keccak, ecdsa, etherjs

I'm trying to get the signature using etherjs in a react native project which should be compatible with ECDSA.sol,
When i try to get the signature with metamask it returns totally fine. but when i try to get it through etherjs or even web3 in react native this gives totally different signature.

Lets say,

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

export async function signAndVerifyMessage(privateKey, message) {
 // Set up the wallet using the private key
 const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);

 // Sign the message
 const signature = await wallet.signMessage(message);

 // Verify the signature and recover the signing address
 const signerAddress = ethers.utils.recoverMessage(message, signature);

 return { signature, signerAddress };
}

Valid Hash = 0x157c0529ea08c1bc8101f54e7b054679a901e1ecc0182d4a9a7f5985d96259c6

Signer = 0x6c3486B5D63251389C8F737Cbd9568E06C2154B4

valid private key for signer = 0x2de74cf307adbdbdd0e3ad4dbdd50d99280239e4724a42bc00dc7d65e8947d91

Valid Signature through Metamask = 0xd5b8e981620fe459faafdf0e3585bc3a9282b008fb6f9d028537e798b2cec577749f02af2eda3a6f0a86938f1faae6a45ddff3d4614d60138b2530d520577afd1b
```

Looking forward to hear.
Thanks